# Python: type of response.cookies

Tags: python, list

I am using the requests module of python. In one of the post calls I am getting response cookies. I wanted to read them so I did:

```
if a in response.cookies:
    print "Found"
```

then I did : `print type(response.cookies)`. This gave me `<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>`

then I did: `print response.cookies`. This gave me `<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie a=asdasdd for v.n>]>`

The type says it is of type Class. The printing of the variable gives a list and I am able to access it like a dictionary. Please explain the `print response.cookies` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think there's a contradiction here. The [RequestsCookieJar](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/cookies.py#L172) class implements the dictionary interface by subclassing [`collections.MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html), so you can access items by key.

Comment: the contradiction is that the actual type of the response.cookies is a list as shown by the print of the response.cookies. But the type is that of class.

Comment: But that's just the [`__repr__` of the CookieJar class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/http/cookiejar.py#L1741), which lists the cookies the jar contains.